# CakePHP 3: Use of components and utility classes in Shell

Tags: shell, cron, cakephp-3.0

I am building cron job using Shell in CakePHP 3.

In my application, I have used a Plugin which provides several components and utility classes which interact with third party APIs (e.g. Instagram).

Can I use those components/utilities from plugin into my Shell/Task? If yes, can you please explain what is the correct way to use? If no, what is the workaround solution for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer!!

We can not use Components in our Shell or Task. We should convert them in Utility classes or stand alone library.

Thanks to [josegonzalez](https://github.com/josegonzalez) for explanation.